# Highlight the clicked page number

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have page number in my react application. Right now when I click on page number the click or current page number doesn't get highlighted or show in different color. I have a className="text-success" which if added will make the text green. I want to add it dynamically to the number which is clicked. How should I do it

This is pagination div (page nunbers)

```
<div className="pagination-media">
                                        <a href="#" onClick={this.getPreviousPage} className="text-success">
                                            <span className="fa fa-chevron-left"></span> &nbsp;
                                            PREV
                                        </a> &nbsp;
                                        {page_number_array.map((item, i) => (
                                                <a href="#" id={`page-${item}`} className="page-no-m"
                                                   onClick={() => this.pageNumberClicked(item)}>{`${item} `}</a>
                                            )
                                        )}
                                        &nbsp;

                                        <a href="#" onClick={this.getNextPage}
                                           className="text-success"><b>NEXT</b> &nbsp;
                                            <span className="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: You need to save the current page number and then use that to determine if the page is selected.`className={'${this.state.currentPage === item ? 'text-success' : ''} page-no-m'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save `currentPage` in state to know what the currently active page is. Then you can conditionally add the `text-success` class to each link:

```js
let page_number_array = [1,2,3,4,5];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentPage: 1
    }
  }
  pageNumberClicked = num => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: num
    });
  }
  getPreviousPage = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1 > 0 ? this.state.currentPage - 1 : 1
    });
  }
  getNextPage = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1 <= page_number_array.length ? this.state.currentPage + 1 : 1
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pagination-media">
        <a href="#" onClick={this.getPreviousPage} className="text-success">
          <span className="fa fa-chevron-left"></span> 
          &nbsp;PREV
        </a> &nbsp;
            {page_number_array.map((item, i) => (
              <a 
                href="#" 
                id={`page-${item}`} 
                className={`${this.state.currentPage === item ? 'text-success' : ''} page-no-m`}
                onClick={() => this.pageNumberClicked(item)}
              >
                {`${item} `}
              </a>
             ))}
              &nbsp;
                <a href="#" onClick={this.getNextPage}
                  className="text-success">
                    <b>NEXT</b> &nbsp;
                    <span className="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
              </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.text-success {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```